# How can I determine if my phpunit test is running in a separate process?

Tags: php, phpunit

Is there any function I can use that would return whether my phpunit test is being run in a separate process using the following?

```
@runTestsInSeparateProcesses

@preserveGlobalState disabled
```

I am trying to write a conditional statement such as

```
if ( _being_run_in_separate_process_ ){

}

else{

}
```

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the property `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::runTestInSeparateProcess`. Like this:

```
if($this->runTestInSeparateProcess) {
    ...
}
```